# paypal subscription for multiple product using paypal api

Tags: php, paypal

I am  trying to do Paypal subscription, but i did not getting any demo or sdk related Paypal subscription with multiple product. it only allow me to insert only one product information at time.

So unfortunately i had to combine all information and price in one product.
Is there any solution regarding this issue?

Comment: have you tried paypal sdk from github?

Comment: I had a lot of issues with PayPal SDK. Here is really good REST API and everything is explained well: https://github.com/amirduran/duranius-paypal-rest-api-php-library

Comment: You can add multiple products/items to the paypal order.

Comment: thanks @Mr.M it will help me , if you have any script regarding this then please give me link. thanks

Answer (score 0):

On [this](https://github.com/amirduran/duranius-paypal-rest-api-php-library) website you can find a very nice REST API.

Here is example how to make multiple items:

```
<?php

$paypal = new DPayPal(); //Create an object
$requestParams = array(
    'RETURNURL' => "http://yourwebsite.com", //Enter your webiste URL here
    'CANCELURL' => "http://yourwebsite.com/payment/cancelled"//URL where user will be redirected if he/she cancel the payment
);


$item = array(

    //Total order amount and currency    
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => "155",//This has to be equal to sum of all items
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'GBP',
    'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT' => "155",//This has to be equal to sum of all items


    //Item 1

    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => 'Item 1',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => 'Item 1 description',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0' => "55",
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0' => '1',

    //Item 2
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1' => 'Item 2',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1' => 'Item 2 description',
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1' => "100",
    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1' => '1',
);

//Call SetExpressCheckout
$response = $paypal->SetExpressCheckout($requestParams + $orderParams + $item);

if (is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Success') { //Request successful
    //Now we have to redirect user to the PayPal
    $token = $response['TOKEN'];

    header('Location: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=' . urlencode($token));
} else if (is_array($response) && $response['ACK'] == 'Failure') {
    echo "Error";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: thanks, and how can i implement it in recurring payment? `CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile` . here is the request which im using `string(506) "METHOD=CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile&VERSION=64&PWD={PWD}&USER={USER}&SIGNATURE={SIGNATURE}&TOKEN={TOKEN}=bluezeal+softnet&SHIPTOSTREET=kolkata&SHIPTOCITY=kolkata&SHIPTOSTATE=West+Bengal&SHIPTOZIP=700114&SHIPTOCOUNTRY=IN&PROFILESTARTDATE=2011-07-01T0%3A0%3A0&DESC=Test+Recurring+Payment%28%241+monthly%29&BILLINGPERIOD=Month&BILLINGFREQUENCY=5&AMT=1&CURRENCYCODE=USD&IPADDRESS=::1&BUTTONSOURCE=PP-ECWizard" `